# How to keep constant a value in n cells in Excel and changing it after the end by adding a fixed number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to keep a value constant in 4 cells in excel and then to change it by adding a fixed value and keep the new value for 4 more cells constant. In the following code you can see the desired outcome.

```
Starting value:            
3

Fixed value:
5
Number of iterations:
4

Table that I want to create:
3
3
3
3
8
8
8
8
13
13
13
13
```

Until now i have succeeded to repeat given values in the desired cells as follows:

```
Values
1
2
3

Table
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

by implementing the following excel function:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MOD(FLOOR((ROW()-1)/5,1),COUNTA($A:$A)),0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put 3,5,4 in **A1** through **A3** and then In **C1**:

```
=$A$2*(ROUNDUP(ROW()/$A$3,0))-($A$2-$A$1)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An option to do as a user defined function: I'll assume little prior knowledge, but that you know how to create a macro. If not then look here for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/excel_macros/excel_creating_a_macro_using_vba_editor.htm
t
If you want to do this in VBA then you can create a user-defined function which takes as its inputs your 3 variables (`staring_value`, `fixed_value`, `number_of_iterations`) and returns an array of values.

```
Option Explicit
Public Function calculate_output(ByVal starting_value As Double, _
                                  ByVal fixed_value As Double, _
                                  ByVal number_of_iterations As Integer, _
                                  Optional ByVal number_of_levels As Variant) As Variant()

  If IsMissing(number_of_levels) Then number_of_levels = 3

  Dim result() As Variant
  ReDim result(starting_value * number_of_iterations - 1, 0)
  
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim j As Integer
  
  For j = 1 To number_of_levels
    
    For i = 1 To number_of_iterations

      result(i + (j - 1) * number_of_iterations - 1, 0) = starting_value + (j - 1) * fixed_value

    Next i
  
  Next j
  
  calculate_output = result

End Function
```

Comment: Nice idea.......you can make a dynamic array and avoid the "copy down".